# Is there really a relation between light intensity and color saturation?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light

Going through [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness) on Wikipedia, under the saturation section, I came across "The purest (most saturated) color is achieved by using just one wavelength at a high intensity, such as in laser light. If the intensity drops, then as a result the saturation drops"

I'm unable to determine if this is the case. Isn't saturation determined for a given brightness or lightness level, being roughly related to the excitation purity? So just having that single wavelength or small band of wavelengths should render a color fully saturated.

Also, in the book "Color Appearance Models" I found this: "For given viewing conditions and at luminance levels within the range of photopic vision, a color stimulus of a given chromaticity exhibits approximately constant saturation for all luminance levels, except when brightness is very high."

Am I missing something?